# Why local martingale property is important in Girsanov theorem?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In [Girsanov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem) theorem, the change of probability measure variable $Z_t = \frac{dQ}{dP}|_{\mathcal{F}_t}$, why does it need to be a martingale with respect to measure $P$ for the change of measure $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ to exist?

I am having trouble understanding this. Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

After reading up about Girsanov theorem and martingale theory, I can come up with the following observations. First if we have a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and two probability measures $P$ and $Q$ for which Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ exist, then  for each $\mathcal{F}_t$ there exists a Radon-Nikodym derivative $D_t$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $D_t$ is a uniformly integrable martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $P$.

Now if we have measure $P$ and a martingale $Z_t$ with filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ we can define set function $Q=Z_t\cdot P$ defined on $\cup \mathcal{F}_t$. It will define a unique probability measure $Q$ on $\sigma(\cup \mathcal{F}_t)$ if $Z_t$ has additional properties, $EZ_t\equiv 1$ being one of them.

Going into more details requires reposting some book on this topic, which is not feasible. I read [this one](http://books.google.com/books?id=1ml95FLM5koC&printsec=frontcover&dq=revuz%20yor&hl=fr&ei=bJOVTY-GCcmbOqW8-acH&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). Chapter VIII is a good read for clarifying things up. Naturally other books can be found.

Note that this is really a comment not an answer, I suggest trying to ask at math.SE, with details what exactly you did not understand, the question in the current format can be answered in many different ways, since there is a lot of things going on.

Comment: @mpiktas: I think you should write that $Q$ is defined on $\sigma(\cup \mathcal{F}_t)$, since $\cup \mathcal{F}_t$ is not necessarily (and indeed, usually is *not*) a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @cardinal, you are right, although in the book I cited, only union is used. I will have to recheck.

Comment: @mpiktas: interesting, as that is a well-known and highly regarded reference. You might be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/the-union-of-a-strictly-increasing-sequence-of-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma) on math.SE.

Comment: @mpiktas On the contrary, at the very next line after they define the set function, the authors mention that *it has to be extended to a probability measure* on the generated sigma-algebra.

Comment: @cardinal See comment above.

Comment: @Didier Piau, @cardinal the book tells that the $Q$ is defined on $\cup \mathcal{F}_t$ which is algebra, and it has to be extended to $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$, which presumably is $\sigma(\cup\mathcal{F}_t)$. I will fix the text.

Comment: @Didier Piau, @cardinal, I've found another typo, hope now everything is ok.

Comment: @Didier, thanks for joining the conversation. I didn't have a copy of the text handy, so could not check it myself.

Comment: @cardinal Hi. I guessed so, no problem with that.